# How to define different URL-segments (routes) in different language in TYPO3?

Tags: url, typo3

I am using routes in config.yaml for nice URLs for my own extension in a current TYPO3 10 like this:

```
routes:
   -
     routePath: 'search'
     _controller: 'MyModule::all'
```

Now I would like to have different routePaths depending on the current language. That means f.e.

```
   routePath: 'suche'
```

if the user is on the German version of the website.

I would appreciate any hint how to implement that in config.yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with a aspect:

```
routes:
  - routePath: '/{locale-search}'
    _controller: 'MyModule::all'
aspects:
  locale-search:
    type: LocaleModifier
    default: 'search'
    localeMap:
      - locale: 'de_DE.*'
        value: 'suche'
```

Source: [TYPO3 explained](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#localemodifier)

Comment: Please accept it as solution for your question.